# MySQL forcing filter on primary key makes query much faster

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables Order and Item. They look roughly like this.

```
CREATE TABLE `Order` (
  `order_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `item_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `time` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`),
  INDEX `combo_id` (`item_id` ASC, `order_id` DESC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_order_item`
    FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`)
    REFERENCES `Item` (`item_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);

CREATE TABLE `Item` (
  `item_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`),
  INDEX `status` (`status` ASC) VISIBLE);
```

And I have a query to get the last 5 orders of each item whose status is not 'D'.

```sql
select * from 
(SELECT order_id, item_id,
        rank() over (partition by Item.item_id 
                     order by order_id desc) drank
 FROM Order
 JOIN Item ON Item.item_id = Order.item_id
 WHERE Item.status != 'D' ) tmp 
 WHERE tmp.drank <= 5;
```

I have about 300K rows in the Order table and 500 rows in the Item table. This query runs slow, it takes about 2 seconds. The execution plan is like this.

```
table |type   |possible_keys    |key    |ref  |rows   |filtered|extra
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Order |range  |item_id,combo_id |item_id|NULL |117003 |90.00   |Using index condition; Using where; Using MRR; Using temporary; Using filesort
Item  |eq_ref |PRIMARY,status   |PRIMARY|NULL |1      |52.57   |Using where;
```

However if I add a filter `order_id > 0` to force the query engine to use order_id as an index, the query is much faster. It only takes 1 seconds. Now execution plan is like this.

```
table |type   |possible_keys            |key    |ref  |rows   |filtered|extra
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Order |range  |PRIMARY,item_id,combo_id |PRIMARY|NULL |117003 |45.00   |Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
Item  |eq_ref |PRIMARY,status           |PRIMARY|NULL |1      |52.57   |Using where;
```

I don't really understand why this hack works. Why the composite index `combo_id` does not improve the query speed? Why does forcing on the order_id reduce the filtered number in half? Can someone please help to explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does it work if you phrase the query like this?

```
select o.order_id, o.item_id, drank, i.*
from (select o.*,
             rank() over (partition by o.item_id 
                          order by order_id desc
                         ) as seqnum
      from orders o
     ) o join
     item i
     on i.item_id = o.item_id
where i.status <> 'D' and seqnum <= 5;
```

I am thinking that this can make use of an index on `orders(item_id, order_id)` for the `row_number()`.  That might help the performance.

Comment: Because derived table needs a name, so I named it as tmp and replace the "o" to "tmp". From the execution plan, I can see that the derived table still has a 100.00 filtered. However, this query only take about 1 seconds and is slightly faster than my hacked query. Is this because in my query the join makes the composite index no longer usable?

Comment: @wendong . . . The join probably interferes with optimization.